# JavaScript errors with Easy Appointments plugin, any suggestions?

Tags: wordpress, jquery-plugins

I am using the following plugin: https://easy-appointments.net/

It was working about a month ago. Now it is showing multiple errors.

First it wouldn't find a bootstrap.css.map file in the plugin directory.

Now that I fixed it, the following error is showing and the fields don't show:

[image: Screenshot of errors being logged to the browser console]

I went to jquery.migrate.min.js & jquery.min.js file and changed 3.6.0 to 3.3.2  and the other way around, but it did not work. So now the booking template still doesn't show. The error disappeared, but it still shows

> JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 3.3.2

- What is that file for ? (JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 3.3.2)
- Is there anyone that have had the same issue with this plugin?
- Does anyone have some sort of solution?

My page => https://xn--vitvtt-eua.se/bokning/

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developers of the plugin for assistance with this? If not then the Easy Appointments plugin has a [support forum](https://easy-appointments.net/support-forum/), might want to try posting there to get some help with this issue.

Comment: I contacted them a few time, but they ignored it.
I also sent a mail to see if the paid version does not show these issues or if they would help me if I were to pay for it, but didn't get a reply.
However, from what I read online, other people don't face the same problem.
Recent comments don't show this issue.